# How hot can a dremel 200 get?

Tags: tools

How hot can a dremel get during normal operation and what happens if it stalls? I use a dremel 200 at home and when it's been running for longer periods of time (5 min continious) I notice that it get's hot and seems to run faster.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a word somewhere in there...

Comment: I've read it over and over and can't figure out the word that's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty hard to break a Dremel. From their [FAQ](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/customerservice/faq/rotarytools/pages/demel4000.aspx)

> Q: What are some tips to allow the tool to run cooler?
>
> A: Allowing the tool to run by itself for one minute after use, actually helps cool the tool compared to turning the tool off immediately after use.
>
> Additionally, make sure to avoid covering the vents on the side of the tool with your hands while using it because airflow to the motor is blocked.
>
> Let the speed do the work. Do not bare down on the tool causing the motor to stall. If the motor stall the fan will run slower and therefore not cool the motor as efficiently.
>
> Q: How do I know if the tool is running too hot?
>
> A: A heat sensitive fuse prevents the tool from overheating at a critical level.

Answer (score 2):

Hobbyist tools like Dremels aren't intended for long periods of heavy-duty operation which causes them to stall, which can damage them. You need to get a professional tool with more power.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Kewlio.

Comment: So it turns out that the Dremel 4000 is more robust and stalling doesn't damage it. Time to upgrade.